# Authorization works only with GET requests

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot

I have the following methods in my rest controller:

The first one is a get request:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<PagedResponse<Shop>> getAllShops() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.shopService.getAllShopsSortedByDistance());
}
```

The second one is a post request: :

```
@PostMapping("/like")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> addShop(@RequestParam(value = "shop") String shopId,
                                            @CurrentUser UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
{
    RestResponse restResponse = this.shopService.addShopToLikedShops(shopId, userPrincipal.getId());
    UriComponents uriComponents = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/shops").buildAndExpand();
    return ResponseEntity.created().body(restResponse);
}
```

in the angular service i make the following calls:

```
getAllShops(): Observable<ShopsPage> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': this.tokenService.getToken()
        })
    };
    return this.httpClient.get<ShopsPage>(this.apiUrl, httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(response => {
                return response;
            }));
    }
```

this method call the get method in the controller and works fine.
the second service method:

```
addShopToPreferred(shopId: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.tokenService.getToken()
        })
    };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + "/like?shop=" + shopId, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(response => {
            return response;
        }));
}
```

This service method calls the post controller method, it didn't works, here's the error:

> error: {status: "Unauthorized", error: 401, message: "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource."}

I don't know why the token works on GET but not POST.

**EDIT**
spring security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
Add `JwtAuthenticationFilter` class:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                String userId = this.tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = this.customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the `jwtAuthenticationFilter()` code aswell.

Comment: @rorschach done

Comment: On first glance everything seems to be okay code-wise. Have you debugged it, is the token properly attached to the POST request, does the filter get called or not?

Comment: When using POSTMAN everything works, but if i mad the call from angular the POST requests doesn't work. So i guess it's a client side issue

Comment: Sounds like it. Have you **inspected** the POST request that Angular makes to see if the token is attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake, GET methods in angular accept two parameters:

```
getAllShops(url, headers)
```

but the POST ones accept three:

```
addShop(url, data, headers)
```

so I was passing data instead of headers, here's how the post method should look like:

```
addShopToPreferred(shopId: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.tokenService.getToken()
        })
    };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + "/like?shop=" + shopId, null, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(response => {
            return response;
        }));
}
```